# Change This Method to Generic (Without Collection)

Tags: java, generics

I have the following method, which clones an object using gson to do a deep copy.  Is there a way to make this method generic, or do generics only pertain to objects that belong to a Collection?

```
private Order gsonClone(Order t) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(t);
    return gson.fromJson(json, t.getClass());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make any method or class generic by declaring generic parameters. Since you need the class, pass it as a separate parameter:

```
private <T> T gsonClone(T t, Class<T> type) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(t, type);
    return gson.fromJson(json, type);
}
```

Comment: If `t` is not null, you don't need to pass in the `Class` separately, because you can still call `t.getClass()`.